# JQuery change class and show div when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, dom, checkbox

When a checkbox is checked, I am trying to change the CSS class of an element and show another element.
Currently I have very undry code and repeat the following changing the 0 to 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
    $("#form-0").hide();
    $('#checkbox-0').click(function () {
      $("#form-0").toggle(this.checked);
      $("#div-0").toggleClass("new_class")
    });
```

It works fine with my long winded code; however, when I try to iterate through using a for loop, it breaks.  There is no error but the element is not shown and the class is not changed.

```
    for (var i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
      $("#form-"+i).hide();
      $('#checkbox-'+i).click(function () {
        $("#form-"+i).toggle(this.checked);
        $("#div-"+i).toggleClass("new_class")
      });
    };
```

I am new to JQuery and Javascript, I'm sure I am missing something simple.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried this:
Change the html of the elements like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-0" class="MYCHECKBOX" />
```

And then go through them like this:

```
$for (var i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
    $("#form-"+i).hide();
}
$('.MYCHECKBOX').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).click(function () {
    $("#form-"+index).toggle(this.checked);
    $("#div-"+index).toggleClass("new_class")
  });
});
```

Comment: P.S. The `i <= 10` is not a good way to go through, though. Simpler would be to implement the same way (add `class="MYFORMS"`) and then do `$(".MYFORMS").hide();` instead of the full for-loop

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.  That worked very well and is nice clean code.  Much appreciated!  Just for my personal understanding, when iterating through classes does index always start at 0?

Comment: Yes, the index will start from 0.